# Making parallel and concurrent SignalR requests in flutter using bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, concurrency, signalr, bloc

With latest flutter bloc version , the events are processed concurrently.

here's is the scenario.

1. How to make concurrent signal R requests and show the result of all the requests for each millisecond until certain condition.

Here's what I have done.

1. Able to do single signal R request and get the result with bloc.
2. Also able to do multiple Signal R request once the previous request has been done processing.

What I need

1. To make concurrent or parallel signal r request using bloc while already a signalR request is under processing.

The sample code of the bloc's event

```dart
on<eventName>(
        (event, emit) async {      
          for (final element in event.files) {
            await establishSignalRConnection(uploadChannelId, element.name);
            final DocumentUpload uploadAttachment =
                await _Repository.upload();          
            emit(uploadedState(
                 emittedStateProperty
                ));
          }
        },
      );
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What *exactly* do you need help with? Do you have a BLoC? Can you do *one* SignalR request? Can you show the results? And you do multiple requests over a specific time? Can you do them in parallel?

Comment: Hi @nvoigt
Yes , I am having a bloc and can do a  single SignalR request and multiple signal signal R request in sequential[one request after the other].

I need to do request in parallel.

Comment: Can you post that code?

Comment: Event handling code has been posted. Please let me know , if more things needed

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do it like this:

```
on<eventName>(
    (event, emit) async {   
      const results = await Future.wait(   
      event.files.map((element) {
        await establishSignalRConnection(uploadChannelId, element.name);
        return await _Repository.upload();
        });

      // results now is a list of DocumentUploads, after all of them finished in parallel              
      emit(uploadedState(emittedStateProperty));
    }
  );
```

Please note that opening that many connections and sending one file over each is probably slower than having a signalR endpoint that just accepts multiple files. So if you can change the backend, that might be the better way, performance wise.

Comment: Please note that I want to intermittently emit the state to show the uploaded percentage at each millisecond for all the list of files. 
This can't be done, if we emit only once, after all files were uploaded as  in the above template shared.
Please note that the Backend can accept multiple files at a time.